# Sending maps over Bluetooth using Native Tizen

Tags: android, maps, tizen-native-app

I am currently working on an application for a Samsung Gear S2 Watch that is utilizing Native Tizen Maps. I send coordinates to the Gear S2 from a Android application and mark the coordinates on the map. This works perfectly fine with one exceptions:

```
The Gear S2 has to be connected to WiFi in-order to load the maps to the gear.
```

Is there a way to send maps from the Android Device to the Gear S2 by means of Bluetooth, without making use of WiFi? I have done some initial research and cant seem to find a way to do it. 
Any suggested sources and/or tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending map tiles data and syncing coordinates over Bluetooth will be very time consuming and slow, that's why WiFi is used. I don't know about native support but this can be achieved with socket programming which you will have to manage manually.